# 3D Lighting (OpenGl)

Tags: opengl, lighting

Hello
I want to create a nice 3D scene to show some 3D models.
How I should manage the lighting to made models appear quite 3D!
Some thing like Solidworks!
How many light source I need? Directional or position? Where? What kind of material for bodies?

Comment: This question is kind of vague.

To give your models the appearance of being three-dimensional, a simple directional light will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this kind of stuff for fun, so here's what I can say about the different types of lighting techniques:

1. **Directional lights** act like the sun; their rays are parallel, so they might look strange when in the wrong context.
2. **Point lights** are (obviously) points. They have no shape, and just emit rays out of a single point in space. They are invisible, but don't give realistic results (as point lights don't exist in nature).
3. **Area lights** are flat objects which emit light, like those umbrella things they use in photography studios. They are visible if they are in the camera's view, and they create quite realistic results. Usually they're squares or rectangles, but circles work too.
4. **Mesh lights** are actual 3D objects which are used as lights. These are the most realistic, but the hardest to compute and render. They look not too much different from area lights, but are useful in some situations (like making a glowing lightbulb).

I do this sort of stuff (as my username suggests), so here are a few tutorials on how to do lighting in a studio fashion:

- **Studio Lighting Tutorial**: http://www.yafaray.org/documentation/tutorials/studiolighting
- **Examples of Different Types of Lights**: http://www.yafaray.org/documentation/userguide/objects#Lights
- **Creating Nice Materials**: http://www.yafaray.org/documentation/userguide/material
- **Tons of Other Tutorials**: http://www.yafaray.org/documentation/userguide/

If you want the *best* results, ditch OpenGL and get an unbiased rendering engine, like the free [LuxRender](http://www.luxrender.net/en_GB/index).

And for a good 3D modelling program (to import your 3D scene to render), try the free program [Blender](http://www.blender.org/). It's my favorite ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I need some hints to implement this in OpenGl!

Comment: BTW I saw the links. Those are very nice!!!

Comment: Can you give me some example codes!

Comment: Yes of course, But I can't find what I exactly need?

Comment: Ok, I finally found my answer, It was normals  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867442/3d-lighting-opengl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867442/3d-lighting-opengl)

Comment: Are they not supplied by the mesh itself? The normals are just vectors perpendicular to the triangle, usually facing away from the inside of the object.

Comment: It seems not! I supplied normals manually with glNormal() and it worked