# 3D Lighting (OpenGl)

Tags: opengl, lighting

I already asked this question but I didn't get my answer. Btw I found some thing new.I want to show a 3D model from a wrl file exported by solid works.The file contains triangle's vertices and I am drawing them with glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES), But it doesn't looks nice and doesn't seems quite 3D!  I tried gluSphere to draw an sphere in that scene with same lighting setting and it seems very nice and 3D!!!!
Is there some thing about Glu ?
Should I use Glu for draw triangles?

Comment: Can you at least post a (link to a) screen shot of your scene. Without a lot more information it's going to be virtually impossible to say what's wrong - if anything.

Comment: Did you read [chapter 6](http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter06.html) of The Red Book?

Comment: [http://www.iimmgg.com/image/b7d00755fef146af065fada51f563fb6](http://www.iimmgg.com/image/b7d00755fef146af065fada51f563fb6)

Comment: @ Ishtar: Not completely but I am on it .... (Thank u)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a good shading you should also supply normals for the triangles.

Comment: Thank u, Can you help me with an example?
How can I do it?

Comment: @mrbm: If your file format supplies you with normals, pass them with glNormal3f, if not you've to calculate the normals yourself. For this you take the cross product of the vectors spanning each triangle (this is the *face normal*), then for each vertex you add the normals of the faces the vertex is used in and normalize the resulting vector.

Comment: Yes it worked,  [http://www.iimmgg.com/image/77a01bb08db598aa5715c0987a41d986](http://www.iimmgg.com/image/77a01bb08db598aa5715c0987a41d986)  I am so happy, Thank you very mach!

Comment: It seems the length of normal is determines the amount of light, Am I right?

Comment: @mrbm: Yes, this is because the length of the vectors scales the scalar product used to determine the illumination. That's why you must normalize the normals (i.e. scale the normal vector that it has the length 1). This is done by v_length(v) = sqrt(v.x² + v.y² + v.z² + ...) = sqrt( v · v ) ; v_normalize(v) = v / v_length(v); '·' denots the scalar product (also called dot product)